# Windows (10) Special QtCreator command as default app for C & H-files

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association

on one PC with Windows 10, I have this as the default app for C & H files, and I really like it :

[image]

This somehow calls on Qt Creator which assigns these nice icons (there are actually more for further file types)

How can I replicate this setting on a different computer, also with Windows 10 (or maybe another version of Windows, for other people with a similar question) ? Opening the menu in the screen shot only allows me to select an app, not a particular way to call it, as seems to be set.

Comment: Have you installed Qt Creator on both systems and configured both systems to open .C files with Qt Creator? Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question

Comment: The field to choose any program is found at the end of the list of apps, all the way down at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Not sure I understand either comment. I observe that one PC has this special command that gets called upon opening some files and want to replicate this. The field to choose any program only allows me to chose a program, not to type in a special command.